# How to correctly set the operation id when logging using ILogger?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the `ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider` to log my messages to application insights. This is how it is currently configured:

```
var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
         .ConfigureLogging((context, logging) => {
                logging.AddApplicationInsights(
                    configureTelemetryConfiguration: (config) => config.ConnectionString = connectionString,
                    configureApplicationInsightsLoggerOptions: (options) => { });
         })
```

My question is how can I set the correct operation ID every time a message is logged. I currently have a service that provides me with the correct operation ID but I can't find a way to automatically set it before each message is logged. Is there a way to create a middleware to do this?

Because I did not have in mind to log into application insights from the beginning, all the logs are not done using `BeginScope` right now.